# Pandas memory issues after fetching data from a SQL db

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to fetch a huge dataset from our SQL db into a pandas df. First I read the data by

`dataSQL = pd.read_sql_query(query, con, chunksize=1000)`

since the data is huge, to avoid memory issues I use a chunksize of 1000. Then I want to append the results of the dataSQL generator object in a pandas df, so I do:

```
chunkyData= pd.DataFrame() #create an empty df

for chunk in dataSQL:
  chunkyData = chunkyData.append(chunk, ignore_index = True) # append chunks to the empty df
```

But this is where I get again a memory issue, error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 3, in
>      File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line
>   225, in concat
>       copy=copy, sort=sort)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line
>   289, in **init**
>       obj._consolidate(inplace=True)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4457, in
>   _consolidate
>       self._consolidate_inplace()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4439, in
>   _consolidate_inplace
>       self._protect_consolidate(f)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4428, in
>   _protect_consolidate
>       result = f()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4437, in
>   f
>       self._data = self._data.consolidate()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4098,
>   in consolidate
>       bm._consolidate_inplace()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4103,
>   in _consolidate_inplace
>       self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line
>   5069, in _consolidate
>       _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 5089,
>   in _merge_blocks
>       new_values = _vstack([b.values for b in blocks], dtype)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 5135,
>   in _vstack
>       return np.vstack(to_stack)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 234, in
>   vstack
>       return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0) MemoryError

I am stuck with the memory issue. While the generator object helped to fetch the data, now I cannot add this data to a dataframe because of memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question directly, but do you need to read all of the data into memory at once? What is the final goal that you have for this data? Here’s a couple of reasons why I’m asking.

**Displaying the data to the user:**
If you’re just pulling the data to present it, you can use pagination which most flavors of SQL can easily handle within the LIMIT clause. If you show 100 results per page and the user selects page 10, you simply calculate (10-1)*100 = 900 and run the query again with “LIMIT 900,100”

**Non-aggregate processing:**
If you are processing each record independently of the rest of the data, you can simply use the generator to iterate, process each row, and store the output somewhere else (ideally by inserting into another SQL table). The result should be a much smaller set of data and you can query that and easily store it in memory if needed.

**Aggregate processing:**
If you need to run aggregate functions across the entire data, you can do this within your SQL query. Any modern SQL database will make light work of pretty complex processing with an optimized query. If putting the burden on the SQL db is not an option because you need to use some particular Python library, then you may need to find a map-reduce solution that works. If you have access to a spark cluster, this would be an ideal use-case.

**EDIT:**

Another option would be to use a stochastic gradient descent (regressor or classifier. You can then do a partial fit, allowing the model to optimize the coefficients one sample at a time. This will let you use a generator to read in one line at a time from your csv which of course, depending on the size of your csv could take a while (maybe read in chunks similar to what you were doing with pandas).

Here's some sample code assuming each row in your csv file has a sample of all ints and your last int in the row is your target.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import csv
import numpy as np

clf2 = SGDClassifier(loss='log')
filename = 'yourfile.csv'

with open(filename, "rt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        sample = np.array(row, dtype=np.int)
        clf2.partial_fit(sample[:-1], sample[-1])
```

Comment: I need to develop a model on this data (Non-aggregate processing), but I am fine to store the data in 2/3 csvs and then perform modelling on that

Comment: @Kay see the edit I just made, maybe using an SGD with many partial fits will work for you.